Перехватить клавишу win c#
Подскажите возможно ли как то перехватить клавишу win? Чтобы она не вызывала пуск в приложении. Всё варианты которые нашел, из старых winlocker-ов ,неработают. Такое ощущение что Microsoft усилил защиту.
Другие кнопки неинтересуют.

Все так, нажатие на клавишу определить можно, но перехватить нельзя.

Можно переопределить? Или только добавить свое действие?

Перехватить или переопределить нельзя

Понял, спасибо.
